# How do I get the entire admob movie clip to show before the next method

Tags: java, android, admob

How do I get the entire admob movie clip to show before the next method call and if the user presses the back button or the user shuts down the ad the next method won't start.

"the interstistial ad is just working fine."

Sample of my code:

```
public void freeGoldOrNot(){

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();

       //Start this after the entire mInterstitialAd is shown
       // if not, do not call
       beginPlayingGame();

    else{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try again!",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile. close the `if` with `}`

Comment: Forcing an ad before starting the game sounds like a good way to lose users.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an `AdListener` to know when the user has closed the ad.
Start you game on Ad closed.

But your customers aren't going to like this mode of operation.

Comment: Thanks i vill try with the AdListener,. it's not that I'm forcing a user to view advertising, it is so that the user can choose to press a button and then see advertising and will then be rewarded with a certain number of coins.

Comment: NB incentivising users to watch ads for in game currency is against Admobs policy